# How to generate QDomain file using entity classes in maven dependency?

Tags: hibernate, maven, querydsl

I want to generate QDomain using entity classes in maven dependency. And my entity classes in Maven : org.XXX.XXX:domain:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT. But cannot generate QDomain using command "clean install". Here is my pom.xml file.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/qDomain</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        <options>
                            <querydsl.entityAccessors>true</querydsl.entityAccessors>
                        </options>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

...
...

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xxx.xxx</groupId>
        <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Is there any help my code detect entity classes in maven dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved by generated Qdomain in domain project not in main project